# How to use a specific Nokogiri version for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm trying to run a Rails application that I wrote a couple of years ago, however I keep getting this error when I run `rails server`:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) - did find: [nokogiri-1.5.6] (Gem::LoadError)
```

I'm pretty confused, since I have Nokogiri v1.8.2 and v1.10.7 installed and see them under `.gem/ruby/2.3.0` and `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0`. I don't see Nokogiri v1.5.6 though, so I'm not sure where the application is getting that from.

I tried adding

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.10', '>= 1.10.3'
```

to the Gemfile, as well as

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.6'
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can change the `GEM_PATH`, but hopefully there's another solution I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokogiri is used by Rails, so you don't need to add it to your Gemfile, but you can update the version in your `Gemfile.lock` using:

```
bundle update nokogiri
```

Comment: ah interesting. I'm getting another issue when doing that: ```Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.```
But I'll try looking more into that, thanks!